# Javafx load a new fxml file into a scrollpane

Tags: java, javafx

Is this possible to load a new fxml file into a scrollpane

for more detail view this image

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiPnk.png)

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code shows how to use FXMLLoader to turn a String into some FXML objects.
Then the usual GetChildren().Add(XX) can be used to assign to wherever you need.

Robert

```
package ic.ac.uk.relationshipvisualiser.app;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class tmpTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start tmpTest");
        launch(args);
        System.out.println("Start tmpTest");
    }

    final Group m_root = new Group();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        String sample_fxml = 
                "<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>" +
                "<?import javafx.scene.Group?>" +
                "<Group xmlns:fx=\"http://javafx.com/fxml\">" +
                "       <Label fx:id=\"Name\" style=\"-fx-font-weight: bold;\" alignment=\"CENTER\">It worked</Label>" +        
                "</Group>";

        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(sample_fxml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        FXMLLoader l = new FXMLLoader();

        Group mG = (Group) l.load(stream);

        m_root.getChildren().add(mG);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(m_root));

        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: watch this image i want to add fxml inside scrollpane [link]( http://i.stack.imgur.com/DiPnk.png)

Comment: not on start by during runtime or in any function executed after startup

Comment: I was trying to show how to load a string into a set of FXML objects. In the example I did it on start up but exactly the same code can be placed in any event. You will also want to alter it to read the string from the actual FXML file.

Comment: can you provide me link that show how to read string from fxml file

Comment: please also give me a hint for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116989/javafx-how-to-get-selected-data-from-observation-list-column

Answer (score 0):

Further to my previous answer to show reading from a file:
First create a file c:\test.fxml containing:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<Group xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
<Label fx:id="Name" style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" alignment="CENTER">It worked</Label>     
</Group>
```

Next use the following code:

```
package ic.ac.uk.relationshipvisualiser.app;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class tmpTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start tmpTest");
        launch(args);
        System.out.println("Start tmpTest");
    }
    final Group m_root = new Group();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("c:\\test.fxml");
        FXMLLoader l = new FXMLLoader();
        Group mG = (Group) l.load(stream);

        m_root.getChildren().add(mG);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(m_root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```